# Why null reference exception?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can any one help me, visual basic application prompting me a message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". i have 2 project in one solution. One is developed in c# and other is in vb. i am calling a method of c# project in vb project. the vb code is:

```
    Dim objUserProfileSystem As New IndexCatalogSystem() // c# project class
    Dim Ds_Themes As New DataSet()                       //dataset
    Ds_Themes = objUserProfileSystem.FillThemes(msg, 1)  //c# class method returning dataset
    ThemeID = Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ThemeID")     //getting themeid from dataset
```

I am calling vb application from c# application. like:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\\DocumentViewer.exe ", " (" + val + ") ");
```

when i debug vb project individually it works properly and when i call vb application from c# application, it prompting error. is i missed out any .net framework reference?

Here is Fill_Theme Method.

```
   public DataSet FillThemes(ref String msg, int UserID)
        {
            try
            {
                //inilialize the Connection 
                Connection objCon = new Connection();
                if (objCon.Ini_Connection(ref msg) == true)
                {
                    //declare data set
                    DataSet DsGroup = new DataSet();
                    //declare data adapter
                    SqlDataAdapter DaRole = new SqlDataAdapter();

                    //initialize Sql Select Command and fill dataset
                    DaRole.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ThemeID FROM DMUsers where UserID = " + PARA_User_ID, objCon.con);
                    DaRole.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(PARA_User_ID, SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserID;
                    DaRole.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    DaRole.Fill(DsGroup, "DMUsers");

                    //Dispose object
                    objCon.Dispose_Con(ref msg);
                    DaRole.SelectCommand.Dispose();
                    DaRole.Dispose();

                    //Return Folder Dataset
                    objCon.Dispose_Con(ref msg);
                    return DsGroup;
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Connect ion fail contact Administrator";
                }
                return null;
            }
```

The Whole Method which i develop to call themes.

```
  Private Sub Themes()
    Dim objUserProfileSystem As New IndexCatalogSystem()
    Dim Ds_Themes As New DataSet()
    Ds_Themes = objUserProfileSystem.FillThemes(msg,modCommon.UserID)
    ThemeID = Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ThemeID")

    If Ds_Themes IsNot Nothing Then
        If ThemeID = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("6")
            THEMES3Blue()
        ElseIf ThemeID = 2 Then
            THEMES2Olive()
        ElseIf ThemeID = 3 Then
            THEMES1Silver()
        Else
            THEMES1Silver()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: At what line you are getting the exception

Comment: Based on your last paragraph I'd suspect it has something to do with passing a relative path as a parameter to the called application that is not relative to the calling application's working directory.

Comment: What is `val` in your code..?

Comment: Adding to Josh comments, may be "Ds_Themes" is null if you are loading themes from any path relative to the application. You will have better help if you could tell the line number where you are getting the exception.

Comment: "val" is the initial argument for vb project and that is: FILEPATH=,CONSTRING=server=abcMachine;database=xyz;User ID=sa;Password=1234,FTPSERVERIP=abcMachine,FTPUSERID=dumy,FTPPASSWORD=as123,USERNAME=Administrator. @VishalSuthar

Comment: when trying to getting theme id, it prompts me error. @hamad

Comment: i think i am missing any reference. i googled. but cant find any solution.

Comment: I don't think you are missing any reference. You should place the breakpoint on Ds_Themes = objUserProfileSystem.FillThemes(msg, 1) and see what's the parameters going to it and what this method is actually returning in both cases. On the other hand may be there is an option for you to avoid null reference exception by placing null check like if(Ds_Themes != null) ...

Comment: i am calling .exe file, so i cant place breakpoint on DS_Themes. and i already tell you all that when i am run application individuality it works proper. it get DS_Theme, it get ThemeID also. everything is running perfect. while executiong from c# application it prompts me error.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in this line, the problem may be occured:

```
ThemeID = Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ThemeID")
```

Try this:

```
if(Ds_Themes != null) {
 if( Ds_Themes.Tables != null) {
    if( Ds_Themes.Tables.Size() > 0) {
       if(Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows != null) {
         if(Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows.Size() > 0) {
          ThemeID = Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows(0)("ThemeID")
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I use 5 if statement like above 'cause VB.NET does not optimize when calculate the "&&" operator.

Comment: In VB.Net you should use `AndAlso` if you want it to short circuit.

Comment: So, there's only possibility that Ds_Themes.Tables(0).Rows(0) is null, please check this.

Comment: i analyse that DS_Theme is null, the actual question is that: when i execute vb application from other application. (i.e, i link vbapplication.exe with a 'val' parameter) it prompts me error and while i am going to start application directly (i.e, go to specific directory and double click on .exe file) it works proper. why?